# how to share position in leaflet js to other app like google map

Tags: javascript, leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

I want the user to be able to share the location on the leaflet in to other applications like google map:
[image]

Is it possible to do this in a react leaflet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the cords from leaflet position and format it into google maps location url eg https://www.google.com.au/maps/@-30.899698,152.6384419,11z?hl=en